# Add content under and over PDFs with acrofield in Android with iText

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

I have a problem with my Android app: I need to take some PDF with acrofields, and add some content, but not in another page, or in a page in the middle, just under the content of the existing PDF. And then, when I finished, I have to attach another PDF file with acrofield to this.

For now, I have 3 pages: the first PDF with acrofield, the content that I want to add, and the second PDF with acrofield.

Is there a way to compact all in less pages? Because I have a lot of blank space between one page and the other, and I need to do this.

Comment: Please read manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf for the full explanation on what you're trying to achieve. You'll need to read the intro to find out that there's no such thing as *reflow of content*. You'll need to read the part about `PdfStamper` to superimpose one PDF to the other. You'll need to read the part about `PdfCopyFields` to find out about concatenating PDFs with form fields.

Comment: I tried, but i have more questions: 1) How can i get the coordinates where the content of the existing PDF ends? 2) I have to specify the max width of the paragraph or phrase that i want to add? because if it is very long it doesn't go on a new line. 3) If the string is very long, and goes out of the page vertically, how can i get to continue in a new page?

Comment: 1.) That's very difficult. See http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=280 2) That's a rather strange question. It deserves a downvote as it proves you didn't read the documentation. 3) same as 2). Clearly you're trying to run before you've learned to walk. SO is NOT a surrogate for reading documentation.